# Active Record Precision Decimal Values getting truncated

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

So I have two ActiveRecord models where I store lat,lng values as decimals. The two models have different precision and scale for the lat, lng columns.

Here is the first one:

```
 class Location1 < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def change
    create_table :locations1 do |t|
      t.decimal :lat, :precision => 8, :scale => 6, :null => false
      t.decimal :lng, :precision => 8, :scale => 6, :null => false
      t.timestamps
    end
   end

 end
```

And the second one here:

```
  class Location2 < ActiveRecord::Migration

    def change
      create_table :locations2 do |t|
        t.decimal :lat, :precision => 10, :scale => 8, :null => false
        t.decimal :lng, :precision => 10, :scale => 8, :null => false
        t.timestamps
      end
    end

  end
```

So I have this weird bug where for some values of the lat/lng, the post decimal point values get rounded off to zero.

So for `Location1.create(:lat => 12.93475, :lng => 77.63199057430029)`, the `lng` value gets rounded off to `77.0`. If I remove one decimal place, with `lng` value `77.6319905743002`, the value gets stored properly as `77.631991`. But for any number of digits after `77.63199057430029`, the value gets stored as `77.0`.

I figured this happens only for certain values and has nothing to do with the number of places after the decimal point. Even a value like `77.23423234234234234234234234234234` gets stored properly as `77.234232`.

This is happening in rare cases for only some values. At least for this value, I had no issue in the second able Location2. So, with `Location2.create(:lat => 12.93475, :lng => 77.63199057430029)` the value gets stored properly as `77.631990574`. So my guess is that it does have something to do with the precision and scale values, but no idea what.

Any idea what is happening here?

Comment: What version of Ruby and what version of rails are you using?

Comment: Also, which database are you using, what version.

Comment: Using ruby-2.1.2. Using MySQL 5.5. ActiveRecord version 4.2.0.rc1

Answer (score 0):

### Guess #1

Could it be your DB engine? Investigate the schema **from the database directly**, not from the `schema.rb` file. The real source of truth in how your data is being stored comes directly from the database.

I'm basically wondering if for some reason, even though you've specified `decimal`, it's getting stored as a `float`, and you have some kind of rounding/storage issue. Of course I wouldn't expect it to trunctate all the way to `77.0` (you'd expect at least a few decimal places, even in the case of rounding errors), but I'd take a look at your schema either way.

### Guess #2

Any chance that just before the saving process you have some kind of callback or code (in your code base or any supporting gem) that is doing this rounding before storing the value? Maybe something you've forgotten about or overlooked?

### Guess #3

Version-specific issue with ActiveRecord or your database? Have you looked into possible bugs that are specific to the versions of that stuff (or the combination of the two) that may be causing this?

What other research have you done into the issue along these lines?

Comment: Using ruby-2.1.2, MySQL 5.5, ActiveRecord 4.2.0.rc1. Have looked around but not really found anyone reporting this kind of a problem. The bad part is it's not really reproducible. It happens for only some values, like I've put in the question. Can't figure out what these values are.